# how to find the index of a variable in an array inside of a struct inside of another array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, sockets, struct, client-server

I'm trying to find the index where

```
 EventName=NewYearParty; //I know the value of the eventname
```

in the array which name is--> event_array

---

I tried this code but it did not work:

```
index_event = Array.FindIndex(userlister[5].event_array, row => row.EventName == NewYearParty);
```

---

Here is my struct:

```
 public struct Events
    {
        public string EventName;
        public string Organizator;


        public Events(string Name, string Org)
        {

            EventName = Name;
            Organizator = Org;
        }
    }
```

---

Here is my Class:

```
    public class users
    {
        public Socket U;
        public string Name;
        public Events[] event_array;
        public string[] status;

        public users()
        {
            U = null;
            Name = "";
            event_array = new Events[50];
            status = new string[50];
        }
    }
```

---

Here is the other array:

```
 public users[] userlister = new users[50];
```

Do you know any other way to find this index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a bit ugly (because you end up iterating twice), but you can write:

```
Events[] event_array = userlister[5].event_array;
Array.IndexOf(event_array, event_array.First(e => e.EventName == "NewYearParty"));
```

See `Array.IndexOf` for more information ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eddebat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). You could always just use a `while` loop as well:

```
int index = 0;
bool found = false;
Events[] event_array = userlister[5].event_array;    

while (!found && index < event_array.Length)
{
   if (event_array[index].EventName == "NewYearParty")
      found = true;
   else
      index++;
}
//Index of the element in "index"
```

Neither of these is truly safe; the first will throw if the element isn't there, the second will exit out with `found` false if the element isn't there. However, those cases can be managed (implementation left as an exercise), and this gets you most of the way :)

Comment: I can not use event_array alone in this context. Because it is originating from a struct which is pointed by another array. When I write your code it gives this error "event_array does not exist in the current context"

Comment: I tried this and it is not working:( `var index= userlister[5].event_array.IndexOf(userlister[5].event_array.First(e => e.EventName == "NewYearParty"));`

Comment: Error: "No overload for method 'IndexOf' takes 1 arguments"

Comment: There is an exception :( 
**An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll

Additional information: Sequence contains no matching element**

Comment: @bug That would be the exception I was talking about, there *isn't* an event called "NewYearsDay". If there is the possibility of there being no matching element then you should use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First`. Note that because this returns `null` when no match is found, you may get unexpected results out of `IndexOf`.

Comment: there is another exeption when I used the loop code 
**An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in Lab2ServerDuplicate.exe

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.**

Comment: @bug Thats weird. Did you get the `&& index < event_array.Length` part? Thats there to check that exact boundary. Could you debug it any further to see when/where `index` is out of bounds?